# SQLAlchemy check parameters on new instance

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following model on `SQLAlchemy`:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, DateTime, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import datetime


class Site(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'site'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    url = Column(String(64), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Site(id='%s', home_url='%s')>" % (
            self.id, self.url)
```

I can create new instances as:

```
a_site = Site(url='http://stackoverflow.com/')
```

Is any way to check if the parameter is a valid url when I instantiated?

For example call the method `is_valid_url(url)` when the constructor is called and raise an Exception if the `is_valid_url` returns `False`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by define `url` as a `hybrid_property` and implement the:

```
@url.setter
def url(self, value):
    #your logic here
```

as described in http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create constructor as in any python object:

```
class Site(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'site'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    url = Column(String(64), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.url = kwargs.get('url')
        if not is_valid_url(self.url):
            raise NotValidURLException("invalid url address")
        ...
```

just create method is_valid_url somewhere (you can find tons of regex that can check that).